# angularjs ng-repeat doesn't process linebreaks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I'm building a chatapp in angularjs and my autoscroll scrolls all the way down to the bottom of the chat box like it should when there are no linebreaks in the message. However, when there are linebreaks the autoscroll doesn't goes all the way down.

In my scrollDown directive I'm telling the element to scrollTop() all the way down to the bottom of the element's height. What could be the problem here? Thanks

My plunker is here.  When you play around with it make sure to put linebreaks in there.

http://plnkr.co/edit/x0637Z5uVSvKVKEcNRBE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so [here's my fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/yAmblt2XQBq7Ba65bhOb?p=preview) of your plunkr that seems to work. Some notes:

1. I got rid of the extra directive, as it seemed superfluous. Everything is all done in the `scroll-after-repeat` directive.
2. I added a timeout to let the layout do its work to get positions properly.

Answer (score 4):

Seems the event fires just a bit too quickly for the last element to be rendered. Wrapping it in `$timeout` cures the problem

```
$timeout(function(){
   scope.$emit("Finished");
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7s5XjF0IBMk5zdjN52bj?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: not sure why you removed checked answer... question wasn't about optimizing extra directives

Comment: He provided the same answer as you but also provided optimization suggestions for my directives.  I appreciate your answer though.